# Smooth text position and opacity change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I inspected many ways how to do different parts of the task such as change opacity on scroll or change position on scroll but still don't understand how to put it together.

---

#### What I need:

There is a container that has 4 words that goes in a row. Only 1 word is visible at one time and then another words has to appear from right on scroll down and vice versa on scroll up and so on with each word. I created visual example of what I want:

**Step 1:**

User begins scrolling and text starting appearing from right (example shows **text 1** and **text 2** but it has to be related to each text in the row)

[image]

**Step 2:**

User keeps scrolling and **text 2** goes on the position of **text 1** one while **text 1**'s
transparency becomes less

[image]

**Next steps:**

It's shown on the last 2 images that in the end **text 1** disappears with `opacity: 0;` and **text 2** stands on its place

[image]
[image]

Example above is shown on **scroll down** but when user scrolls up it should work in reverse way and it should work so when user scrolled for **text 2** and keeps scrolling, **text 3** appears and so on

---

**Unfortunately** I cannot share the code I tried because I can't even imagine a way how to approach for this task. But I had some ideas such as create 2 slider **current** and **next** or something like that.

I hope description with images is clear enough because I'm not even sure if I understand it right

Comment: "I cannot share the code I tried" at least share as much as you can, even the HTML and failed CSS is better as it would allow others a better starting point to base an answer from.

Comment: "text 3 appears and so on" and so on means what exactly? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the height of the `<body>` element arbitrarily to introduce a vertical scroll.

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Create a container for the words. Use `position: fixed` to keep the container on screen when we scroll.

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.words {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="words">
</div>
```

Add in the texts, on top of each other inside the container.

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.words {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="words">
  <div class="word">Foo</div>
  <div class="word">Bar</div>
  <div class="word">Baz</div>
</div>
```

Have the all words apart from the first to the extreme right of the container. The `170px` is an arbitrary amount that is enough to move both the other words off the screen. Clip them out of visibility by applying `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.words {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}

.word:nth-child(n + 2) {
  transform: translate(calc(170px - 50%), -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="words">
  <div class="word">Foo</div>
  <div class="word">Bar</div>
  <div class="word">Baz</div>
</div>
```

Write JavaScript that updates a CSS variable when we scroll.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.words');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  container.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.scrollY);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.words {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}

.word:nth-child(n + 2) {
  transform: translate(calc(170px - 50%), -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="words">
  <div class="word">Foo</div>
  <div class="word">Bar</div>
  <div class="word">Baz</div>
</div>
```

Use this CSS variable to apply `opacity` and adjust the `transform` properties of the `.word` elements. This example passes how many pixels the document has been scrolled as-is to `--scroll`. You may wish to process this value to adjust the amount this affects the CSS or you could also adjust the maths in the CSS.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.words');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  container.style.setProperty('--scroll', window.scrollY);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 9999px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.words {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  --segment-length: 200;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
  opacity: calc(((var(--opacity-point) * var(--segment-length)) - var(--scroll, 0)) / var(--segment-length));
}

.word:nth-child(n + 2) {
  transform: translate(calc(clamp(0%, 170px * ((var(--translate-point) * var(--segment-length)) - var(--scroll, 0)) / var(--segment-length), 170px) - 50%), -50%);
}

.word:nth-child(1) {
  --opacity-point: 1;
}

.word:nth-child(2) {
  --opacity-point: 2;
  --translate-point: 1;
}

.word:nth-child(3) {
  --opacity-point: 3;
  --translate-point: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="words">
  <div class="word">Foo</div>
  <div class="word">Bar</div>
  <div class="word">Baz</div>
</div>
```

This code transitions between words every `200px` scrolled. This is denoted by our value for `--segment-length`.

Comment: Perhaps the final scroll should always show the text but the OP has not made that goal state clear.  I added a comment on the question to ask for that clarification as what you have might work once that is added.

Comment: The final scroll looks exactly how I expected it to be except of the last word that shouldn't disappear on scroll. I didn't mention it in the question so I mark your answer as a right one as it does what I asked for

Comment: @Wongjn but if I need this text to scroll **only** inside the container not body? I mean here we have ```body { height: 9999px }```. On my site I have **header** **main** and **footer** and body shouldn't have scroll but this text should be scrolling inside main

Comment: You'd make whatever element you want scrollable, and adjust the JavaScript to query the scrolling for that element.